# Question on metric spaces.. 2 properties which I don't know whether they apply

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, metric-spaces

Do these two properties hold in all metric spaces. In my textbook, it says they hold in spaces, that have defined scalar products, but I am interested if they hold in generally metric spaces:

$$1.) d(x+z,y+z)=d(x,y)\\
  2.) d(\lambda x, \lambda y)= |\lambda|d(x,y)
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since $+$ and scalar multiplication are not defined.

By the way, they are true for [normed spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space).

Comment: Then would they hold for instance in this example: $ d(x,y)= \frac{\| x-y \|}{ \sqrt{1+ \| x \|^2} \sqrt{1+ \| y\|^2}}$ where $\| . \|$ is the Euclidean norm ?

Comment: @BozidarVulicevic It seems not, as you can easily verify.

Comment: Then when you say generated by a norm you do not mean that d(x,y) is a function of a norm but rather $ d(x,y)= \| x-y \| $ strictly ?

Comment: Exactly. In a normed space, the metric is always referred to $d(x,y)= \| x-y \|$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight.

Comment: But strictly speaking a normed space is not a metric space; it can be made into a metric space by defining $d(x,y)=||x-y||$, as Bozidar said.

Answer (score 1):

No, it only holds in normable metric spaces, spaces where the metric is derived from a norm.

You can take an example of the metric $d(x,y)=|x|+|y|)$. Then $d(x+z,y+z)=|x+z|+|y+z| \neq d(x,y)$ unless $z=0$.